# Match 2 columns in same file and exit zero if matching else proceed Unix

Tags: unix, awk

I have a requirement like File 1 has some employee details, like below

> empid,empname,empdaddress,empsupervisor

```
1234,xxx,street1,6666
2345,yyy,street2,6666
3456,uuu,street3,2345
4567,ppp,street4,9999
9999,kkk,street5,7777
```

Now, i have to match empsupervisor column value with empid, to know if the details of empsupervisor is also present in the file1.
in the file sample, the 2345 is a empsupervisor and its details are present in the file. Same for 9999. But 6666 emp details is not present in the file.

i have to check if details are present in file 1 then check for another record, else exit 0 on complete searching.
I am new to unix scripting. Any suggestion is highly appreciated.
Thanks

I've tried

```
awk 'FNR==NR {h[$1] = $11; next} 
($1 in h) {
    print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$15,'U'
}' file2 file1 >newfile
```

Comment: 'awk 'FNR==NR {h[$1] = $11; next} ($1 in h) {print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10,$11,$12,$13,$15,'U'}'  file2 file1 >newfile... this can match when we have 2 files. I want to perform operation in single file.

Comment: Does it have to be awk? Can you give a sample of 'file2' and the desired output?

Comment: Why don't you use a higher level language like python or ruby? Or store the records in a database?

Comment: File 2 also has same columns only extra 2 columns for flagged values. I have to use Unix scripting

Comment: why do you print until column 15?

Comment: i want to copy the record from file 2 to file 1. Lets circle back to my original problem. How do i check in file 1 if empsupervisor record is present or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work where emp is the filename.

```
comm -23 <(cut -d, -f4 emp | sort -u) <(cut -d, -f1 emp | sort -u)
```

will give you

```
6666
7777
```

It's not clear what you want to do with the result and the other file.

Above code can be rewritten using a function.

```
 p () { cut -d, -f"$1" emp | sort -u; }; comm -23 <(p 4) <(p 1)
```